# How to select only X number of records from mnesia

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

I want to select only X number of records from mnesia. Do we have any function call which provide this functionality?

I am using :mnesia.select to fetch all the records from mnesia table, but I want to fetch only X number of records from mnesia table:

```
Mnesia.transaction(fn ->
  Mnesia.select(
    Person,
    [{{Person, :"$1", :"$2", :"$3"}, [{:>, :"$1", 3}], [:"$$"]}]
  )
end)
```

Answer (score 5):

I am unsure what wrapper for `mnesia` do you use, but the standard library provides [`:mnesia.select/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#select-4) where the third parameter is a number of records to retrieve.

That said, something like this would work:

```
x = 500

:mnesia.select(
  :persons,
  [{{:persons, :"$1", :"$2", :"$3"}, [{:>, :"$1", 3}], [:"$$"]}],
  x,
  :read
)
```

Comment: Perfect this returns me x number of records, but here is a problem: if I put lets say x = 10, then I expect latest 10 records from mnesia, but I get 10 records from somewhere in the middle of the record list

Answer (score 3):

If you use a wrapper like [`Memento`](https://github.com/sheharyarn/memento), it's pretty straight-forward using the `limit` option:

```elixir
Memento.Query.select(Person, {:>, :"$1", 3}, limit: 100)
```

---

<sup>***Full Disclosure:** I'm the author of the Memento package.*</sup>